# Obter e formatar cookies de um requisição

Tags: python, python-3.x

Galera, no PHP eu usava assim:

```
preg_match_all('/Set-Cookie:\s([^\;]+)/mi', $response, $matches)
```

Dei uma olhada na documentação e tentei seguir essa linha de lógica porém não funciona:

Sou amador com python e preciso pegar alguns cookies do request:

```
re.findall('/Set-Cookie:\s([^\;]+)/mi', response)
```

No momento é `python` puro, não tem nenhum *framework* envolvido ainda, no futuro irei usar `django`.

o código todo está assim:

```
import requests
import re

response = requests.get('https://twitter.com')

print(re.findall('/Set-Cookie:\s([^\;]+)/mi', response))
```

Comment: Guilherme, então a sua pergunta é como pegar Cookies de uma requisição e não como usar expressões regulares em Python? Parece ser um [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%c3%a9-o-problema-xy). Seria interessante você [editar sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/389183/edit) e adicionar nas tags quais frameworks/bibliotecas você está usando e qual é o seu objetivo final.

Comment: Dei uma editada @fernandosavio, no momento é o que consigo explicar oaksokas a requisição do twitter é simbolica, escolhi essa url pra estudar, poderia ser google...

Comment: Você está usando o módulo requests.. já é uma biblioteca :-)

Comment: Seria legal você conferir a [documentação](https://3.python-requests.org/user/quickstart/#cookies) da biblioteca, pois ela já trata disso tudo pra você.

Comment: É eu vi essa documentação, mas vou ver com mais atenção, vlw fernandosavio :)

Comment: Algo como `response.headers['set-cookie']`. Muito mais fácil que extrair isso com expressões regulares.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, sim mas futuramente eu precisaria extrair, por exemplo `cookiename=valor;` precisaria extrair apenas o valor, por isso o interesse de saber regex em py

Comment: Em PHP, as barras só delimitam a regex, mas não fazem parte da mesma, e o `mi` são [modificadores](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), que mudam alguns aspectos do funcionamento da regex. Em Python é diferente, então seria algo como `re.findall(r'Set-Cookie:\s([^\;]+)', response, flags = re.I | re.M)`. Outro ponto é que regex varia muito entre as linguagens, então nem sempre o que funciona em uma vai funcionar exatamente do mesmo jeito em outra (não deve ser o caso desta, mas é importante saber o que cada linguagem suporta antes de simplesmente copiar a regex)

Comment: Eu não copiei, eu apenas dei o exemplo de como faço no PHP. Mas vlw pela reposta